# ERROR TypeError: context._applyGlobalCompositeOperation is not a function in Konva js

Tags: konvajs

I am getting following error while initializing layer using Konva.

ERROR TypeError: context._applyGlobalCompositeOperation is not a function

we have 2 animation projects 
1) we have bundled konva library and using it in another project and not installing through npm.
2) now we have created another project and using it in the same project but this time we have installed through npm while using this package

now when we are navigated between these 2 pages (projects) within the same project. we are getting the above issue.

can anyone help us on this issue?

complete error here

```
ERROR TypeError: context._applyGlobalCompositeOperation is not a function
at Konva.Rect.drawScene (konva.js:9074)
at konva.js:8354
at Konva.Collection.each (livesportsvisualization.min.qTFK9r.js:29) **(its installed from bundled file which also have konva internally )**
at Konva.Layer._drawChildren (konva.js:8353) **( installed from NPM )**
at Konva.Layer.drawScene (livesportsvisualization.min.qTFK9r.js:44)
at Konva.Layer.drawScene (konva.js:11805)
at Konva.Layer.draw (konva.js:4504)
at Konva.Stage.add (konva.js:10837)
at Builder.drawBackground (basketball-animation.js:42)
at BasketBallComponent.drawBase (basketball-animation.js:2407)
at BasketBallComponent.ngAfterViewInit (basketball-animation.js:2440)
at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:12748)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:12715)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:12698)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13853)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14635)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11619)
at core.js:5918
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:5918)
at core.js:5751
at ZoneDelegate.3104.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
at ZoneDelegate.3104.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.3104.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at NgZone.run (core.js:4577)
at Object.next (core.js:5751)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4342)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at EventEmitter.emit (core.js:4322)
at checkStable (core.js:4725)
at Object.onHasTask (core.js:4773)
at ZoneDelegate.3104.ZoneDelegate.hasTask (zone.js:441)
at ZoneDelegate.3104.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount (zone.js:461)
at Zone.3104.Zone._updateTaskCount (zone.js:285)
at Zone.3104.Zone.runTask (zone.js:205)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at ZoneTask.3104.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)
```

Thanks,
Srinivas.

Comment: How do you navigate between pages? Full page reload? Or with modern routing without refresh?

Comment: without refresh its angular app no page relaod

Comment: Probably it is a conflict of using several Konva version together. You actually should see a warning about it in a console. Currently, konva doesn't support such a case.

Comment: any alternative like clearing konva library from cache like that? because working fine when we are navigating from newer version page to older version page but vice-versa is not working.